# Can we make an android app using Unity 3d and Native Android SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

Is possible to make an android app having action bar, list view and other Native android stuff but for showing animations instead of using OpenGL can we use Unity-3D? If it is not possible please recommend me some tutorials to learn OpenGl or some library which makes it easier to animate things like, Two circle's being connected by a line such that line starts from circle 1 and ends on circle 2 ?

Comment: I think you can get the asset template of Android Native UI and then use it in unity. Otherwise I heard something called checking Android Development Project box when building app in unity, to make it able to be opened in Eclipse (or similar). Never tried myself, tho. Btw, if you are developing in unity, I assume it's a game, if so, why does a game need to have Android Native UI? I think it'll look weird

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can , maybe its awkward , but you can make even more professional looking apps in the design with unity and c# , its the only utility that use every aspect in graphics in android and have tons of assets and plugins out in the market , most people thinks its for the games , but its the only alternative right now for android studio and java .